# Overloading a method with a difference of list/array of type . Is that a good practice?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, overloading

I have a method in businessservice as follows,

```
public void ProcessModelId(int modelId){
   //method logic for a modelid....
}
```

Now the requirement is to send list of ids, so should i modify existing method or can i overload another method wit list of ids? like below?

```
 public void ProcessModelIds(List<int> modelIds){
   foreach(var i in modelIds){//method logic for each modelid....}

    }
```

which one is a good practice in design perspective?
or that doesn't matter at all?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the requirement, if you no longer have to pass single integer modelId to the function, then it is advisable to modify the existing function as there is no reason to overload it and have redundant code that is never used.

On the other hand, if you want to have the choice of passing an `int` or a `List<int>`, overloading would be the way to go. Although, personally, I'd just modify the existing function, as even if you want to pass just a single integer, you can still pass it as a list with just one element.